# How to trim white spaces in bootstrap validator?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, jsp

```
'email': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                    },
                }
            },

            confirmEmail:{
                validators:{
                      notEmpty: {
                      },
                      identical:{
                        field:'email',      
                      },
                }
            },
```

Can anyone please help me how can I get rid of trailing and leading spaces before I do the form submit. I am using bootstrap validator. When I enter spaces after or before entering the email address, it says invalid email address.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
validators: {
    callback: {
        callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
            $('#email').val(value.trim());
            return true;
        }
    },
    emailAddress: {
        message: 'The value is not a valid email address'
    },
```